# How to enable Legend picking with a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

The following example [from the matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html) shows how to make a legend "pickable", such that you can toggle the lines visibility by clicking on their legend:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.linspace(0, 1)
y1 = 2 * np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y2 = 4 * np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
line1, = ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, label='1 Hz')
line2, = ax.plot(t, y2, lw=2, label='2 Hz')
leg = ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)

lines = [line1, line2]
lined = {}  # Will map legend lines to original lines.
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(True)  # Enable picking on the legend line.
    lined[legline] = origline


def on_pick(event):
    # On the pick event, find the original line corresponding to the legend
    # proxy line, and toggle its visibility.
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    visible = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(visible)
    # Change the alpha on the line in the legend, so we can see what lines
    # have been toggled.
    legline.set_alpha(1.0 if visible else 0.2)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

Specificaly, the line `leg.get_lines()` allows to retrieve the "line legends". When plotting scatterplots, this method does not retrieve the scatters legends, as shown by the following :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, label='Scatter Plot')
line = ax.plot(x,y, label="Line plot")

legend = ax.legend()

lines_from_legend = legend.get_lines()
print(lines_from_legend) # [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000027C11058670>]
```

I am trying to make a legend pickable/toggle-able like the example from the doc, such that it works both on line plots and scatterplots, from a given `Axes` only - and no reference to the previously plotted lines/scatters. Basically, I am missing an equivalent way to `leg.get_lines()` but for scatters:

```py
import matplotlib.collections
# for a given axes, ano nothing else : 
leg = ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)
# for lines
lines = [ax.lines[i] for i in range(len(ax.lines))]#[line1, line2]
leglines = leg.get_lines()
# for scatters 
scatters = scatters = [i for i in ax.get_children() if isinstance(i, matplotlib.collections.PathCollection)]
legscatters = ????
```

Matplotlib version : 3.6.3

Comment: You're making it too difficult by switching to `.scatter`. Use the positional `.plot` formatting options to have a line, points or both. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K78G6.png)

Comment: I see your point, but the scatter plots are actually generated by another library (seaborn), so I do not control the creation of the plot ([see](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/ff446eef75f87253c1e53f0e06f5307d2644ca00/seaborn/relational.py#L548C21-L548C28)).

Comment: Ah, the post didn't say anything about seaborn. In any case, seaborn is a high-level API for matplotlib. There's nothing the seaborn can do that can't be implemented directly with matplotlib  and pandas. You might be able to get the `on_pick` function to work, but I'm not sure how.